# JavaScript Loop Inside Loop Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I have loop inside loop like this:

```
var len = bolumlerUnique.length;
function bolumleriGonder() {
    for (i = 0; i < bolumlerUnique.length; i++) {
        elementBolumler = $("[bolumid=" + bolumlerUnique[i] + "]:checked");
        console.log(elementBolumler);
        for (j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            console.log(elementBolumler[j])
        }
    }
}
```

`bolumlerUnique` is an **array** --> ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
I have radio inputs and find elements with this code

```
$("[bolumid=" + bolumlerUnique[i] + "]:checked");
```

But in the second loop `console.log` writes `undefined`.
But elementBolumler is defined global variable.

Comment: is `bolumid` an attribute on your HTML elements?

Comment: no `var` before your `elementBolumler` variable initiliasation, also maybe no need for the second loop you have access to the element via the `elementBolumler` (once syntactically correct) in the second loop you are trying to access the index of a single item.

Comment: @NickParsons yes i have custom attributes on my html

Comment: @FrancisLeigh all variables defined globally

Comment: your `elementBolumler` is simply not an array... so `elementBolumler[j]` would return undefined

Comment: If your `elementBolumler` variable is a correctly queried element then there is no ned to access it via square bracket notation. you just plainly have it there and then.

Comment: If you're wanting to do specific things with the `elementBolumler` once you've queried it, why not have your variable decleration within the loop? if the variable is global then that variable will only be the last element your query after the loop is finished.

Comment: I mean, can't you just give all your bolumler elements a common class, and iterate through them with `$(".mybolumlerclass:checked")`  All that id stuff seems like a lot of work.

Comment: `elementBolumler` isn't array, but it *is* a jquery collection, so `elementBolumler[0]` is perfectly valid as it's the same as `elementBolumler.get(0)` or `elementBolumler.first().get()` and elementBolumler.innerHTML would give an error as it's not a DOM node.

Comment: Many thing that should not work in your code, already the :checked selector in radio is supposed getting only one element so elementBolumler[j] in loop does not make sens, i advice you to tell us what are you trying to achieve instead of trying to correct the actual code

Comment: If you can provide an [mcve] that shows your HTML structure and an explanation of what you are trying to do, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `len` variable is have a value it must work with your codes.

Comment: Yes, problem was my len variable, because len value is 0, i changed with bolumlerUnique.length and works, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> in the second loop console.log writes undefined.

To answer the question as (almost) presented:  *"why do I get undefined with `$()[j]`?"*

Within jquery, if you attempt to get an element by index that's larger than the number of items in the jquery collection, you get `undefined` (not array out of bounds as it's not an array), ie:

```js
var divs = $(".d");
console.log(divs[0])
console.log(divs[1])  // undefined
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d">d1</div>
```

---

The issue is with:

```
var len = bolumlerUnique.length;
for (j = 0; j < len; j++) {
```

When you iterate over

```
$("[bolumid=" + bolumlerUnique[i] + "]:checked")
```

it will only have as many items as are checked that match the one `id`.  So it's highly likely that

```
elementBolumler.length !== len
```

As noted in the comments to the question, `[bolumid=" + bolumlerUnique[i] + "]` is a `radio` so it will only ever return one item.

Your logic for the inner loop index `len` is incorrect, but it's not clear what it should be - possibly:

```
elementBolumler.length
```

as in:

```
function bolumleriGonder() {
    for (i = 0; i < bolumlerUnique.length; i++) {
        elementBolumler = $("[bolumid=" + bolumlerUnique[i] + "]:checked");
        console.log(elementBolumler);
        for (j = 0; j < elementBolumler.length; j++) {
            console.log(elementBolumler[j])
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const checkboxesIWantToMessWith = [2, 4, 6]

checkboxesIWantToMessWith.forEach(id => {
  const checkbox = document.querySelector(`input[bolumid="${id}"]`)
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    // Do my stuff
    console.log(`checkbox bolumid="${id}" is checked`)
  } else {
    // Do other stuff
    console.log(`checkbox bolumid="${id}" is NOT checked`)
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" bolumid="1" checked />
<input type="checkbox" bolumid="2" checked />
<input type="checkbox" bolumid="3" checked />
<input type="checkbox" bolumid="4"  />
<input type="checkbox" bolumid="5" checked />
<input type="checkbox" bolumid="6" checked />
```

Comment: `elementBolumler` isn't array, but it *is* a jquery collection, so `elementBolumler[0]` is perfectly valid as it's the same as `elementBolumler.get(0)` or `elementBolumler.first().get()` and elementBolumler.innerHTML would give an error as it's not a DOM node.

Comment: Valid point, i've changed my answer to not use JQuery now as `querySelector` provides allot of the API

Comment: I suspect you may be right and OP has checkboxes, not radios